# IBM Domino - Which document is unique for Groups

Tags: websphere, lotus-domino, lotus, tdi

Is there a unique document value for each groups inside a `names.nsf`?

I would like to add and remove members inside a group over TDI Notes Connector.
I realize when I choose the `ListName` as link criteria, there are sometimes multiple lookup results.

Please note that we do have multiple domino servers. The `names.nsf` and the groups are replicating, so I'm looking for a document (unique ID) for a group which is not changing on different domino servers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every document in Notes/Domino has a UniversalID that is a unique identifier. Unfortunately this identifier is NOT saved in any field. But I googled a bit about TDI Notes Connector and found [this page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSCQGF_7.0.0/com.ibm.IBMDI.doc_7.0/referenceguide17.htm)

And it seems that TDI adds the universalid as field to every document it retrieves as **$$UNID**:

> The following Entry Attributes are added by the Connector itself (their values are not available as document items):
>
> $$UNID - the Universal ID of the document (see "The $$UNID and
> $$NoteID Attributes")
> ...
> **The $$UNID and $$NoteID Attributes**
> The Universal ID (UnID) is the value that **uniquely identifies a Domino document**. All replicas of the document have the same UnID and the UnID is not changed when the document is modified. **This value should be used for tracking objects during synchronization**. The Universal ID value is mapped to the $$UNID Attribute of Entry objects delivered by the Connector. The value of the $$UNID Attribute is a string of 32 characters, each one representing a hexadecimal digit (0-9, A-F).

Comment: TDI allows you to create a link criteria with UNID - so this is the answer that im looking for. Great, thanks a lot Torsten.